# Unable to find an element in div class

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to click an element..it is span located in div. I could get the locator. but when I used it in the code, it says element is not clickable.

```
WebElement BookEditor=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='appNavPanel']/div/span[2]"));
WebElement BookEditor=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.tooltip.fade.right"));
```

The name of element is Book Editor. Here is the html.

```
<div class="cb-AppNav js-app-nav">
  <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" class="cb-IconButton is-active" title="" data-original-title="Book Admin"></span>
  <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" class="cb-IconButton cb-AppNav-button icon-utility-page js-app-nav-page-config" title="" data-original-title="Book Editor"></span>
  <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" class="cb-IconButton cb-AppNav-button icon-utility-standard_objects js-app-nav-page-manager" title="" data-original-title="Book Manager"></span>
</div>
```

When I move the cursor to the icon, it shows the below code. Otherwise its hidden.

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" class="cb-IconButton cb-AppNav-button icon-utility-page js-app-nav-page-config" title="" data-original-title="Book Editor"></span>
<div class="tooltip fade right" style="display: block; top: 57px; left: 50px;">
<div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
<div class="tooltip-inner">Book Editor</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually you're locating using CSS class, I think locating classes appended dynamically that's why you're unable to locate after mouse over, you should try using xpath to locate element after mouse over on the element as `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(.,'Book Editor')]")).click();` and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Try to move to the element to make it visible before clicking on it

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement bookEditor = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-original-title='Book Editor']"));
action.moveToElement(bookEditor).perform();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.tooltip.fade.right")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Moving the element works fine. But I got  this error. org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.tooltip.fade.right"}
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)

Comment: @Ela Are you trying to click on the opened tooltip or on the or on the original element?

Comment: I am trying to click on the original element. tooltip snippet might have confused. my bad :( I have tried using the xpath and css lookup along with action moveToElement. It didn't work.

Comment: @Ela Try `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-original-title='Book Editor']")).click();`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am getting the existing error now :(  
unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (25, 123). Other element would receive the click: <div class="vex-overlay"></div>

Comment: @Ela Try JavaScript excuter `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-original-title='Boo‌​k Editor']")); JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

Comment: neither implicit wait nor explicit wait work..tried with thread.sleep(). it works! not sure how it works!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the html, I'm assuming that the non-clickable element is some sort of 'fly-out'?

That seems like the most probable, and I believe that's what Guy is alluding to in his response.

I would suggest that, in addition to the Actions implementation, that you also apply a WebDriverWait for the element to be clickable before proceeding.

> From Guy's response:

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement bookEditor = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-original-title='Book Editor']"));
action.moveToElement(bookEditor).perform();
```

> Add in a WebDriverWait to resolve the Element being displayed:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10); //Up to 10 seconds for the state to match the desired conditions.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickble(By.cssSelector("div.tooltip.fade.right")).click();
```

Comment: yeah this seems to be non-clickable element. I am getting the same error even after adding WebDriverWait. div.tooltip.fade.right is actually not visible. I can see only when I move the cursor on it. Thanks.
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.tooltip.fade.right"

Comment: Using the Actions class should cause the fly-out to open, and make it visible/clickable (at least that is the intent).  Does the Actions.perform not cause that to occur?

Comment: If the flyout is opening and you're seeing the 'unable to locate element', then my next check would be to verify your lookup for the element you want to click.  Are you certain your css lookup is correct?

Comment: Actions class doesn't do any changes. Neither moving the element to location nor throw the error. Strange. Css lookup seems to be correct. I actually got that from firebug.

Comment: This approach *should* provide you what you're looking for, I'm not sure where to take it from here.  I'd maybe try other lookups, besides css, for both the 'bookEditor' and 'div.tooltip.fade.right' references.   The Actions implementation should cause the flyout to appear.  I'd get that to work first, then look at the click target.

Comment: The locator is correct. there seems to be problem with DOM. Neither implicit wait nor explicit wait work..tried with thread.sleep(). it works! I am not sure what the problem was? thanks